# SOAP UI Get Token for Oauth1.0

Tags: web-services, soapui

I would like generate an access token for Logging into NetSuite. On Soap UI , to generate the token , the following boxes need to be filled out

Consumer Key & Secret

Temporary Token URL, Authorization URL , Access Token URL and Redirect URL

Can anyone please explain in detail what exactly needs to go into all the 4 URL fields . I have the Consumer Key and Secret .

I checked the SOAP UI tutorial on this and it didn't help

Comment: Have you checked its documentation?

Comment: Yes , the document talked about Retrieving Access Tokens , but it wasn't helpful . I would like to have a few examples of the type of URL's that need to go into each field . That way I can search the NetSuite Documentation for them